# Guardar TableView en mysql javafx

Tags: mysql, javafx, guardar

Tengo un tableview con varios tablecolumn de diferentes tipos (integer, String, double, double) y varios registros (rows). Quiero almacenar los registros asociados a esas columnas (uds, concepto, precio, total) en una base de datos mysql (la base de datos tiene también esas mismas columnas) cuando pulse el boton guardar, **pero no se como capturar esos datos** para almacenarlos en la BBDD.

[image]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Coloca el codigo donde tu boton añadir deberia hacer el trabajo.

Comment: Eso lo tengo claro, mi problema es saber cual es el código para capturar (recoger, obtener) los datos de las celdas y donde debo debo almacenarlos. Una vez tenga esos datos, yo se como almacenarlos en la BBDD, también se como y donde implementar el boton y otras acciones.